# @EnvironmentVariable not being passed to child views

Tags: swiftui, environment-variables

I have 2 views - which I want to navigate between, and have a viewModel object shared between them as an EnvironmentObject. I keep getting the "A View.environmentObject(_:) for TidesViewModel may be missing as an ancestor of this view." error - but none of the solutions I have found seem to work. Please find below my code. The following is the first view:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {

@ObservedObject var tidesViewModel: TidesViewModel = TidesViewModel()

var body: some View {
    NavigationView
    {
        List
        {
            ForEach (tidesViewModel.stations.indices) {
                stationid in
                HStack
                {
                    NavigationLink(destination: TideDataView(stationId: tidesViewModel.stations[stationid].properties.Id))
                    {
                        Text(tidesViewModel.stations[stationid].properties.Name)
                    }
                    
                }
            }
        }
    }.environmentObject(tidesViewModel)
}
}
```

and below is the child view - which throws the error.

```
import SwiftUI

struct TideDataView: View {

@EnvironmentObject var tidesViewModel : TidesViewModel

var stationId: String

init(stationId: String) {
    self.stationId = stationId
    getTidesForStation(stationId: stationId)
}

var body: some View {
    List
    {
        ForEach (tidesViewModel.tides.indices)
        {
            tideIndex in
            Text(tidesViewModel.tides[tideIndex].EventType)
        }
    }
}

func getTidesForStation(stationId: String)
{
    tidesViewModel.getTidalData(forStation: stationId)
}
}
```

For completeness - below is the Observable object being passed:

```
import Foundation
import SwiftUI

class TidesViewModel: ObservableObject
{
private var tideModel: TideModel = TideModel()
var currentStation: Feature?

init()
{
    readStations()
}

var stations: [Feature]
{
    tideModel.features
}

var tides: [TidalEvent]
{
    tideModel.tides
}

func readStations()
{
    let stationsData = readLocalFile(forName: "stations")
    parseStations(jsonData: stationsData!)
}

private func readLocalFile(forName name: String) -> Data? {
    do {
        if let bundlePath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: name,
                                             ofType: "json"),
           let jsonData = try String(contentsOfFile: bundlePath).data(using: .utf8) {
            return jsonData
        }
    } catch {
        print(error)
    }
    
    return nil
}

private func parseStations(jsonData: Data) {
    do {
        let decodedData: FeatureCollection = try JSONDecoder().decode(FeatureCollection.self,
                                                   from: jsonData)
        //print(decodedData)
        tideModel.features = decodedData.features
    } catch let jsonError as NSError{
        print(jsonError.userInfo)
    }
}

func getTidalData(forStation stationId: String)
{
    let token = "f43c068141bb417fb88909be5f68781b"
    guard let url = URL(string: "https://admiraltyapi.azure-api.net/uktidalapi/api/V1/Stations/" + stationId + "/TidalEvents") else {
        fatalError("Invalid URL")
    }
    var request = URLRequest(url: url)
    request.httpMethod = "GET"
    request.setValue(token, forHTTPHeaderField: "Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key")
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
        guard let data = data else{ return }
        do{
            let decoder = JSONDecoder()
            decoder.dataDecodingStrategy = .base64
            let decodedData =  try decoder.decode([TidalEvent].self, from: data)
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.tideModel.tides = decodedData
            }
        }catch let error{
            print(error)
        }
    }.resume()
}
}
```

Comment: EnvironmentObjects are not necessarily injected at init. You should consider running your function in onAppear as apposed to init (which is supposed to be lightweight anyway)

Answer (score 0):

You need to attach the modifier `.environmentObject()` directly to the view that will receive it. So, in your case, attach it to `TideDataView`, not to the `NavigationView` around it.

Your code would look like this:

```
NavigationLink {
    TideDataView(stationId: tidesViewModel.stations[stationid].properties.Id)
        .environmentObject(tidesViewModel)
} label: {
     Text(tidesViewModel.stations[stationid].properties.Name)
}

// Delete the modifier .environmentObject() attached to the NavigationView
```